# Why does my coffee spin the opposite way that I spin the cup?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life, vortex

I was just drinking a latte in a large cup, and when I spun the cup (doing that smooth one handed “mixing” thing that you usually see with a mixed drink or something) I noticed the design on and the foam was spinning the opposite way I was spinning the cup.

Why is this? Because I understand why water will not spin very much, then spin once it stops, but I can’t understand why my coffee spins in the opposite direction. Is it because the foam is more viscous?

Comment: Are you holding your cup in the same orientation, and moving it in a circle? Or are you spinning the cup in place around an axis going from the top to the bottom of the cup?